# Using jquery selectors to render reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am using jquery for ajax in the build of a test app whilst learning react.

Is it possible to use to jquery selector as the target to render react components?

This is from the [react tut](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html).:

```
React.render(
    <FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

This does not work but i don't even know if it is possible:

```
React.render(
    <FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />,
    $('#content')
);
```

Thanks,
John

Comment: Perhaps, unwrap it from jquery? $('#content')[0]

Comment: And if you're using modern browsers, look at `document.querySelector` as jQuery probably isn't necessary for many typical "find an element" scenarios.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Awesome! I had never seen this before!!

Comment: +1 to use `querySelector()` as we approach 2020.  [See my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447073/#answer-58227904) to override `render()` and use selectors

Comment: or just vuejs ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
React.render(
    <FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />,
    $('#content')[0]
);
```

Comment: If your #content is a react component you can also make use of "refs". `this.refs.content.getDOMNode()` instead of using jQuery. The component/element should be at the same level or passed as a props. When called you should at `ref: content` to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could override ReactDOM.render() to accept both `Element` and DOM selector strings:

```
ReactDOM.render = (origFunc => {
  return (element, elementOrSelector, callback) => {
    const el = (elementOrSelector instanceof Element)?
          elementOrSelector : document.querySelector(elementOrSelector);
    return origFunc.call(ReactDOM, element, el, callback);
  }
})(ReactDOM.render)
```

Use either option:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>Hello</div>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>Hello</div>,
    '#content'
);
```